# Gridview FindControl inside SelectedIndexChanged event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a `TemplateField` in my ASP GridView, and now I want to write a small logic for a checkbox in the gridview. I am trying the `FindControl` code to no success, I've used these combinations...

```
Dim chkChosen As CheckBox = 
'GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Checkbox1")
'DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("Checkbox1"), CheckBox).Value
'chkChosen = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Checkbox1")
```

I commented them as I've used a combination of those three to no success. They all give me the same error... "RowIndex is not a Member of SystemArg...". All this is under a `SelectedIndexChanged` protected sub.

Comment: ur get error bcz e.RowIndex is not valid in selected row index changed.......event....

Comment: oK... so under what type of event should I put it? Or do I need to change the RowIndex for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
Dim chkChosen As CheckBox = CType(GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("Checkbox1"), CheckBox)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I had a similar code but couldn't get it to work, heh. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Get By Gridview Selected Row Index..lyk this

```
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

cHeckbox chk=row.FindControl("chk");
```

Comment: i adjsuted the code to VB.. `Dim GridViewRow As Row = GridView1.Rows.SelectedIndex` and got this error "Error 1 'System.Data.SqlClient.Row' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'. "

Comment: Gridview1.Rows.Selected in gives index number only.You have to write lyk this  GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];